# Using Word-VBA to automatically save as .html when you save a document

Tags: vba, ms-word, msdn

I work in an **entirely offline** facility; it has an intranet site, and is VERY limited to programs available (MS Word is the **only** application available).

I need to be able to open a Microsoft Word document, edit it, and then, when you save the document, it saves the file, and then saves it in .html format as well.

To elaborate, I work in a military Facility that has a network that we cannot have anything installed. On this network is a series of computers. On these computers we keep a log. We want to be able to display this log to anyone who wants to see it. The log is in a .doc format. I want someone to open the log.doc then save it. Once saved it will save an .html file. That file will be displayed for ANYONE on the network to see it.

Comment: I wonder if you can elaborate on your scenrio... both answers given seem to solve the problem, but I fear that your problem is bigger than you have described here.

Comment: @Phlume The problem with both answers is that they don't answer the question of "how can I do this using VB"

Comment: Your above comment was the first mention of VB... Again... you need to elaborate better.

Comment: Are you saying that you're wanting to use VBA to dynamically create a word document and a HTML webpage?

Comment: @Phlume the question is tagged with vba twice. It's important to pay attention to question tags as well as to correctly interpret the question text (which begins with "I work in a facility that is **all offline**").

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified version of what Word 2010's macro recorder produces when you save a file as MHT (single-file html).

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="c:\temp\test.mht", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatWebArchive
```

Adapt as needed.

I'm not sure if Word 2013 supports saving as HTML any longer.  Not all of the office apps do.

Comment: I have Word 2007. But would this save both the mht and the docx?

Comment: It should work the same in Word 2007.  It would save just the MHT.  You'd want to save as DOCX also.  First, in fact, in case saving as MHT/HTML causes any formatting changes.  You'll also want to make sure that MHT works with your group's browsers, but try it first; it gives you one file to deal with instead of one file and a sub-folder of support files to haul around.

Answer (score 2):

The following is adapted slightly from Microsoft's Developer Network. Save this as a Macro in the copy of MS Word used by the client. This Macro will:

Save the document as a .doc(x) file, then as a .HTML file.

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Saver
End Sub

Sub Saver()
    ActiveDocument.Save
        Document_Save
End Sub

Sub Document_Save()
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer

    'Find position of extension in filename
    strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
    intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")

    If intPos = 0 Then

        'If the document has not yet been saved
        'Ask the user to provide a filename
        strDocName = InputBox("Please enter the name " & _
        "of your document.")
    Else

        'Strip off extension and add ".html" extension
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        strDocName = strDocName & ".html"

    End If

    'Save file with new extension
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML

End Sub
```

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to run this macro when they save the .doc? If not, I would have to have 75+ employees make a button to enable macro... not an easy feat.

Comment: @Brandon Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: @Brandon When you save the file it will also save it as a .html file now.

Comment: I saved both a log.docx and a log.html I put this in word and restarted. It did not seem to update the .html when i treid to save the .docx

Comment: OK It works, but it saves the .html to docuements folder. Is there a way to tell it where to save the .html file so that no matter who opens the docx it works?

Comment: ok I got it to work (where I need the .html to go) but the docx is not saving. When I open the .docx it automatically opens the .html (which is fine if the .docx is going to save)

Comment: @Brandon It should let you choose where you want to save it, assuming you are choosing the AutoRun macro.

Comment: Im not choosing any macro to run. When I open the .docx it converts it to .html right away. So everything i Save changes the .html. This is GREAT for the display on the html, but once you make a bunch of changes then save it, then close it. The next person to open the docx it does not show all the changes.

Comment: @Brandon Unfortunately my knowledge with VBA is very limited; if you take this and go to MSDN or similar forums/Q&A sections, they can probably get you squared away without too much difficulty.

Comment: I know how to run macros, but thats why i asked if it was possible to have everything save both to .html and .docx when you just hit the save button because 70+ of the people i work for wont know how to run a macro.

Comment: @Brandon That's why I suggested earlier to add the macro to the image of MS Word. Will all these people be using the same computer? Or will they be using computers that are imaged? Once a Macro is added to an instance of MS Word it stays there until you delete it. Even through logging off and back on.

Comment: it is a .docx on a server that everyone who has access will use.

Comment: how do i add the macro to the image?

Comment: @Brandon Send the Macro to the IT personnel responsible for the imaging of the computers and request that it be vetted/added to every installation of MS Office on the intranet, I guess.

Comment: Having the Macro installed is no big deal. I have the ability to do that. The macro is there, no matter what computer i log into. what you have giving me does 50%, which is more than I had. Now really i just need to get the docx to save lol

Comment: I think you solved my problem, I guess im just not explaining the only issue. With this Macro when you open the docx it opens the .html. I dont mind this, but I would need it to still save the .docx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57704/discussion-between-brandon-and-tylerh).

Comment: if I e-mail you the docx and the .html file can you see if it works or if i did it incorrectlly?